# Instantiating a struct and assigning to a parent struct from the constructor in rust?

Tags: rust, struct, constructor, borrow-checker

I am very sure this has been asked somewhere, but I cannot seem to find a conclusive answer. Suppose I have two structs:

```rs
struct Foo {
  ...
}

// assume Foo has a new function.

struct Bar<'a>{
 foo: &'a Foo
}

impl Bar{
 fn new() -> Self {
    let foo = Foo::new();
    Bar { &foo }
  }
}
```

This wouldn't compile because I'm trying to return a temporary value. If I understand correct, the value is dropped when the function exists and the reference would be a dangling reference. But how would I overcome this? I want a new instance of `Foo` that is distinct for every `Bar`. `Foo` is also used in other structs like `Fizz`, so I can't combine the two. Please give me pointers on how to overcome this.

Comment: Can't `Bar` own the `Foo` rather than merely holding a reference to it?